# Write to file from Windows Service without user rights?

Tags: .net, windows-services

So how can I make my service have normal user rights without providing login information manually?

Comment: Would you consider expanding your question to tell us more about what this service does and why it's a service and not a desktop/systray app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service will run in the context of the user specified for it in the Service Control Panel, so it's up to you which user it uses. :) NETWORKSERVICE etc are the defaults, and you can change it manually or specify the username/password as arguments at install-time depending on what framework/tech you're using.

Comment: I am using .NET for my service and I don't want to manually have to write the user credentials... And I am not going to use an installer for a program that is meant to run only on my home computer...

Comment: Sounds like you want your cake and to eat it. An application can get elevated credentials, but the point of a windows service is that it's non-interactive. If it's just for you for personal use, I'd recommend keeping it simple and setting up the user you want in the services control panel. Also, when I said "installer", I meant the "ServiceInstaller" class in the service (unless you're using TopShelf, that is).

Comment: Well, I planned to send it to more fellow programmers and I don't want to bother them with this... But I will try some more techniques.

Comment: Does not look so good anymore. The user needs to have a password in order to give the service permissions...

Comment: What user do you want the app to run as? You could get the devs to put their username/password in, but then if anyone else is using that machine, the service is still running with the original dev's credentials, so that's not really ideal. I think maybe I've misunderstood the purpose of this service and what you want it for. Perhaps an app running in the system tray is a better option, as it will run in the current logged-on users' context.

Answer (score 0):

You can set what user the service will run with either when installing it or in the service console.

Another alternative is to make the application login with another user when its started, via [impersonation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158) from a some sort of settings file.

Comment: You can set at install time intead.

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, the service is not installed, it's registered and started manually through a C# program. I just want it to be able to write files without manual configuration...

Comment: Added about login via impersonation